# How to prove this simple integral inequality?

Tags: analysis

$\forall a>0$,$$\frac{a}{a^{2}+1} \exp \left\{-\frac{a^{2}}{2}\right\}<\int_{a}^{\infty} \exp \left\{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right\} d x<a^{-1} \exp \left\{-\frac{a^{2}}{2}\right\}$$

Comment: [Here](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/norm-dist-bounds/).

Comment: Thank you very much！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the one hand,$$\int_a^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right) \, dx < \int_a^\infty\frac{x}{a}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2} \right) \, dx = \left[-\frac1a\exp\left( -\frac{x^2}{2} \right) \right]_a^\infty=\frac1a\exp\left( -\frac{a^2}{2} \right).$$On the other hand, define $$g(a):=\int_a^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2} \right) \, dx-\frac{a}{a^2+1}\exp\left(-\frac{a^2}{2}\right)$$ so$$g(\infty)=0,\,g^\prime(a)=\frac{-2}{(a^2+1)^2}\exp\left( -\frac{a^2}{2}\right),$$so $g(a)>0$ for all $a\in\Bbb R^+$.

Comment: Thank you very much！